# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'Fajr'

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to try to do prayers time with api but my problem is this, you can check the api link and see if that I do is fail or right and please give a solve for my problem because I'm tired of it.

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def prayers(ctx):
    api = "http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=karlshamn&country=sweden&method=3&school=1"
    response = requests.get(api)
    result = response.json()
    timings = result["data"]
    fajr = timings["Fajr"]
    dhuhr = timings["Dhuhr"]
    asr = timings["Asr"]
    maghrib = timings["Maghrib"]
    isha = timings["Isha"]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Prayers time Karlshamn", colour=0xa02c2c)
    embed.add_field(name="Fajr", value=fajr, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Dhuhr", value=dhuhr, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Asr", value=asr, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Maghrib", value=maghrib, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Isha", value=isha, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

ERROR

```
Ignoring exception in command prayers:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malaz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\malaz\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 86, in prayers
    fajr = timings["Fajr"]
KeyError: 'Fajr'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malaz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\malaz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\malaz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'Fajr'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replace

```py
timings = result["data"]
```

with

```py
timings = result["data"]["timings"]
```

because fajr and all prayers in timings dict